# parameterizing column name

Tags: python, pandas, parameters

I'm trying to parametrize column name . Here is my psuedocode

```
import pandas as pd
df_scr_crd = {'Subject': ['MATH', 'MATH', 'MATH', 'MATH', 'PSY', 'PSY', 'PSY', 'PSY'], 
        'SCR_STRT': [10, 20, 30, 99999, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 
        'POINTS': [100, 200, 300, 500, 10, 20, 30, 40]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df_scr_crd, columns = ['Subject', 'SCR_STRT', 'POINTS'])
```

I have 3 parameters defined as follows

```
c1 = 'Subject'
c2 = 'SCR_STRT'
c3 = 'POINTS'
```

I want to call data frame column names by the variables; for example, to call `df['Subject']`, I want to call `df[c1]`, where `c1` resolves to `'Subject'`

How do I parametrize the column name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with regular indexing, you need to use double brackets.  The following below is equivalent to `df[['Subject']]`:

```
>>> df[[c1]]
  Subject
0    MATH
1    MATH
2    MATH
3    MATH
4     PSY
5     PSY
6     PSY
7     PSY
```